# datetime.now() appears to be wrong despite timezone

Tags: python-3.x, datetime, timezone

as I am writing now is 14:11 in Dublin (Ireland) but when I try this:

```py
now = datetime.now(tz=pytz.timezone('Europe/Dublin'))
print(now)
>>> 2019-07-02 13:01:38.169066+01:00
```

I get a time that not only is wrong in the hours, is also wrong in the minutes. What's wrong?

Comment: The time. ... Sorry, couldn't resist. What is the System time ?

Comment: uh f**k, my System time is fine, is the first thing I checked but I'm running my jupyter notebook on the remote server of my University (UCD)... I wonder if their time is wrong... is there a command in linux shell that I can run on the server to check the time?

Comment: ok I typed `date` in the shell on the server and the time is wrong... xD I'm gonna try change that and see if it is working

Comment: perfect. you can also run local shell commands in the jupyter notebook using ! before the command. so !date.

Comment: As I though I don't have permission to change the date on the server, I'll have to ask my Professors how to deal with it. Thank you anyway PS. if you want you can post that as an answer